# Why my caption package version is too old

Tags: captions, packages

I am using MikTex 2.9.6942. After `\usepackage{caption}`, I tried to use the `\captionsetup` command. But it gives "Undefined control sequence" error. I searched online and most of people suggest that the caption package is outdated. I checked the package version in MiKTex Console, which looks like this:

[image]

I do not think the installed package is outdated. But when I check the output of LaTeX log, it looks like this

```
    (caption.sty
Package: caption 1995/04/05 v1.4b caption package (HS)

Package: caption v1.4b <1995/04/05> (Harald Sommerfeldt)
\captionmargin=\skip43
\as@captionbox=\box27
\as@captionwidth=\skip44
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \captionsetup 

l.6 \captionsetup
                 [table]{name=New Table Name}
```

It seems that it is using v1.4b by default. I then tried to include the package with `\usepackage{caption}[2018/05/01]`, but then it gives warning

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 5, version
               `2018/05/01' of package caption,
               but only version
               `1995/04/05 v1.4b caption package (HS)'
               is available.
```

I do not know if it is an issue of the latest caption package as I did not see anything regarding this in the package gitLab issue section. Is there anyone else experiencing this error? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: `(caption.sty` shows that you have a local caption.sty in the folder of your document. Remove it.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you so much.